# How can I highlight entities and code keywords in HTML input boxes?

Tags: html, css, input, inputbox, codehighlighter

Let's say I have an HTML input box. I want an input box that highlights code keywords, like this one: http://runnable.com/new/JavaScript , or http://jsfiddle.net/ or something like that. How can I do it? CSS, JS, etc can be used in solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1) Spend ages writing your own solution

Option 2) Make use of one of the results found when searching "javascript syntax highlighter" in Google...

Comment: I don't want normal syntax highlighters, I want user input syntax highlighters, like JSFiddle. There's a difference :D